# Fill a multiline form field with proper line wrap

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

A form that is meant to be printed and filled via handwriting provides a field for a multiline value that can be filled by long text. It is rendered like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                                   |
| --------------------------------- |
|                                   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

So there are two lines with a horizontal rule as guidance for filling the value. I can create this easily with

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\fbox{
  \begin{tabular}{p{10cm}}
    \rule{0pt}{1em} \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{1em} \\
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

However, I now want to add the possibility to fill this field from inside LaTeX, so that it is rendered like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con-  |
| --------------------------------- |
| sectetur adipiscing elit, sed do  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

i.e. I want to give a continuous text value and want LaTeX to properly place it inside the existing lines like a paragraph, with proper word-wrap and spacing. The rendering should otherwise be identical to the empty variant (it is okay for values to destroy the layout if they are too long).

I figure to do this, I would need to throw away the tabular and use a minipage or something that draws horizontal lines between the text lines. At the end of the text I would need to fill additional horizontal lines if the text was too short to produce all expected lines.

How can I do that?

To avoid misconceptions: I do not wish to generate an *interactive* form of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the text in a `\multirow`, but contrary to the normal usage of `\multirow`, leave the horizontal lines in place. You might have to apply a `\baselinestretch` to get the lines positioned  properly. And maybe you have to set some parameters to encourage hyphenation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|}
    \hline
    \rule{0pt}{1em}\multirow[t]{2}{=}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}\normalsize
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do}
    \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{1em} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\multirow` needs a `[t]` for the case that not all lines are filled, but otherwise this works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll add the [t].